# Space in link being replaced with %2520 instead of %20 jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(".row").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s/g,"%20"));
    });
```

When you click on this link it generates with %2520 instead of %20.

```
...position=Administrative%2520Assistant-%2520Robotics
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: And where exactly does JSON come into the picture?

Comment: I create the link from JSON on the site.

Comment: Since you haven't included that part in your question, it seems to be irrelevant. You shouldn't use a tag just because you're using that technology elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably URL encoding the string twice, as `%20` URL encoded, is `%2520`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbqCQ/1/)

Comment: And how to I prevent this?

Comment: I changed the code to

`$(".row").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s/g,"%20");
        });`

still no luck

Comment: Why would that help. Somewhere you are URL encoding the href value, probably on the serverside where the URL is outputted, and like santa you're doing it twice.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, I thought people were saying my code was doing it wrong....